# Loading UITableViewCells synchronously

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an expandable UITableView that adds/removes child UITableViewCells via insert/delete calls from parent cells. Each child cell contains a WKWebView object that I use to render some local HTML strings, and I resize the cells depending on the content height once the strings are loaded.

If I expand the tableview slowly by tapping one parent cell at a time, all works fine. However if I try to load multiple child cells at once, or the same one quickly (e.g. by tapping the parent cell a few times in quick succession), the webview fails to load the content and comes up blank.

I have a feeling its because I'm trying to call WKWebView's `didFinishNavigation` again before the previous load has finished. Is there a way to prevent recalling it before it has finished loading it (i.e. load cells synchronously in the `CellForRowAt` method? Alternative suggestions also welcome. Relevant code below.

Also worth noting - I send content heights from SectionContentTableViewCell (the child) to the view controller via a delegate so I can then call `heightForRowAt`. Heights are stored in a struct to speed up subsequent reloads.

```
class SectionContentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView?
var htmlString = ""
var contentSection: Int = 0
weak var contentDelegate: ContentCellDelegate? = nil

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    webView?.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
}

func configureWebView() {
    webView?.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cases", ofType: "css")!))
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.perform(#selector(webViewLoadCompleted), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.1)
}


func webViewLoadCompleted() {
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = (webView?.scrollView.contentSize.height)!
    print("cellHeight \(String(describing: cellHeight))")
    webView?.frame.size.height = cellHeight
    contentDelegate?.sendContentCellHeightData(cellHeight: cellHeight, section: contentSection)
}
}
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch visibleQuestionRowsArray[indexPath.row] {
        //Value 0 = section cell
        case 0:
            let sectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowHideSectionTableViewCell

            let sectionIndex = determineTrueIndexForSectionCellWith(cellIndex: indexPath.row)

            sectionCell.sectionLabel.text = "Section \(sectionIndex)"

            if indexPath.row+1 == visibleQuestionRowsArray.count {
                sectionCell.expandIndicatorLabel.text = "+"
            } else if visibleQuestionRowsArray[indexPath.row+1] == 0 {
                sectionCell.expandIndicatorLabel.text = "+"
            } else {
                sectionCell.expandIndicatorLabel.text = "-"
            }

            return sectionCell
        //Value 1 = content cell
        case 1:
            let contentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contentCell", for: indexPath) as! SectionContentTableViewCell

            let parentIndex = determineParentForContentCellWith(cellIndex: indexPath.row, currentSegment: currentSegment)

            contentCell.contentDelegate = self
            contentCell.contentSection = parentIndex


            contentCell.htmlString = questionHTMLStringsArray[parentIndex]

            //Check if height already recorded (therefore webview already instantiated)
            let checkOpen = contentHeights.filter({$0.segment == currentSegment && $0.section == parentIndex && $0.width == currentViewWidth})

            if checkOpen.isEmpty == true {
                print("webView instantiated")
                contentCell.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentCell.frame.width, height: 44.0), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
                contentCell.contentView.addSubview(contentCell.webView!)
            }

            contentCell.configureWebView()

            return contentCell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?